# How do I use Flickzeug to get interactive tracebacks from a paste deploy WSGI pipeline?

Tags: python, wsgi, paster

I'd like to use Flickzeug to see interactive tracebacks by adding it to my paste deploy file's `pipeline`. The following doesn't work. What will?

```
[pipeline]
pipeline =
    flickzeug
    myapp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `filter-with` directive in your application declaration.

```
[app:main]
use = ...
...

filter-with = flickzeug


[filter:flickzeug]
use = egg:...#...
...
```

For more information, see the first example in the Filter Composition section of the [Paste Deploy documentation](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#filter-composition).

Comment: The problem I was having is that Flickzeug does not define a paste.filter_factory out of the box, so it doesn't "just work" in a [filter:...] section.

Comment: You can create your own paste.filter_factory entry point, referencing the middleware in the Flickzeug package.